# Unity2d character using WASD movement keeps reversing back to the center and can only travel 1 unit of distance

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

everyone, so I'm trying to create a simple WASD movement based top down character.  I have 5 animation states for forward, backwards, left, and right, and the idle animation is just a static sprite.  For some reason, when I test the game, I can only move one unit of distance on the grid and the character reverses back to the starting point.  Is there any way to fix this?  Thanks so much!

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public Animator animator;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    

    private float speed = 6.5f;
    Vector3 pos;

    public float Speed { get => speed; set => speed = value; }

    void Update()
    {
        pos = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0.0f);
        animator.SetFloat("Horizontal_f", pos.x);
        animator.SetFloat("Vertical_f", pos.y);

        if (Input.GetKey("w")) {
            pos.y += Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("s")) {
            pos.y -= Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("d")) {
            pos.x += Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("a")) {
            pos.x -= Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        transform.position = pos;
        
    }
}
```

Here is the animator:
[animator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfegv.png)

[blend tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dXdi.png)

Comment: You always create a new vector at the start of your update loop. That vector is only going to contain the input axis coordinates, you don't add this to the objects current position, you just scale the vector and then assign it to the objects position. You need to add the pos vector to the existing position. `transform.position += pos`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this, because you always change the new Vector instance in every frame, but you need to get the current position of the object and changing it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public Animator animator;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

   
    private float speed = 6.5f;

    public float Speed { get => speed; set => speed = value; }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    
        animator.SetFloat("Horizontal_f", Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
        animator.SetFloat("Vertical_f", Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

        if (Input.GetKey("w")) {
            pos.y += Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("s")) {
            pos.y -= Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("d")) {
            pos.x += Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("a")) {
            pos.x -= Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        transform.position = pos;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it!!!  The code works like a charm, and I definitely understand now to not change the new vector instance every frame.  However, for some reason, my character is now moving upwards on its own constantly.  Could this maybe have to do with moving upwards being  the default state?  Thank you!

Comment: Actually, nevermind, that was a separate issue with Rigidbody and I fixed it.  Thanks so much again!!!